# CSS Border Radius and background fill issue

Tags: css

I have a top menu like the following image

[image]

As you can see the outer grey border is with border radius. But the selected Home menu filled it as square.

What I want is Home Selected menu should be filled accordingly.

Here's my css codes

```
#navigation-wrap{width:100%; border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 8px -2px #F5F5F5;-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 8px -2px #F5F5F5;box-shadow: 0px 5px 8px -2px #F5F5F5;}
#navigation{margin:0 auto; border: 3px solid #CCC; border-bottom:none; position:absolute; right:0; top:0; -webkit-border-radius:5px; -moz-border-radius:5px; border-radius:5px; -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 4px #EEE;   -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 4px #EEE;  box-shadow:0px 0px 4px #EEE;}
#navigation ul{list-style:none;}
#navigation li{float:left; display:block; letter-spacing:1px; border-bottom: 3px solid #CCC;}
#navigation a{float:left; display:block; height: 30px; line-height:30px; position:relative; padding:0 10px; text-decoration:none; border-bottom: none;}
#navigation a:hover {background: #000; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #FFF; color:#fff;}
.current-menu-item a{background: #000; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #FFF; color:#fff;}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Add identical `border-radius` properties to `#navigation a`.

To apply that to just the `Home` button, use `#navigation a:first-child`. And if you'd like for only the left side of the element to have a border radius, use `border-top-left-radius` and `border-bottom-left-radius`.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. Yes I tried like you suggested with #navigation a:first-child, but it's effect for other menu as well, Please kindly take a look at this screenshot http://i.imm.io/dkDb.png

Comment: Change `:first-child` to `:nth-child(1)`.

Comment: @knightrider: Could you put the HTML and CSS for the navigation into a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: actually html is generated from wordpress because I a trying to working on wordpress menus.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a wordpress generated menu you can get the respective menu id of home by inspecting the element using firebug or other. then you can apply css for border radius directly to a single menu element by calling its respective id